# Is $\mathbb{Ln}(z)$ holomorphic on a circle defined by $\Gamma=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\left|z\right|=1\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that the principal value of $\mathbb{Ln}(z)$ does not include the negative $x$ axis and thus its input consists of only complex numbers with argument in the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$.

However does this mean that $\mathbb{Ln}(z)$ is not holomorphic on a circle $\Gamma$ defined as:

$\Gamma=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\left|z\right|=1\}$

I do not have intuition about the complex logarithm. Any suggestions ?

Comment: the complex logarithm is not continuous in $S^1$. However it is in $S^1\setminus\{-1\}$

Comment: @masacroso what is $S^1$?

Comment: what you defined by $\Gamma$. take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle).

Comment: I just dont see why it is not continuous on the unit circle

Comment: because $\lim_{z\to-1^+}\ln z\neq\lim_{z\to-1^-}\ln z$ for the principal value of the complex logarithm. Here $z\to -1^+$ means $z$ being approach by complex numbers such that $0<\arg(z)<\pi$, and $z\to-1^-$ by such $z$ such that $-\pi<\arg(z)<0$

Comment: I have no longer accepted

Comment: @Masacroso That depends on the used definitions. In the convention I follow, the domain of the principal branch of the logarithm is $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{t\in \mathbb{R} : t \leqslant 0\}$.

Comment: @johnmelon However, whatever convention one follows, the logarithm is not holomorphic on the whole unit circle. In one convention because it's not defined on the whole unit circle, in the other because it's not continuous at some point of the unit circle. For the principal branch, both conventions agree that the problematic point is $-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Daniel pointed in the comments the principal value of the complex logarithm can have slightly different definitions

$$\ln:\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}\to \Bbb R+i(-\pi,\pi],\quad z\mapsto \ln|z|+\arg(z)\tag{1}$$

where $\arg(z)\in(-\pi,\pi]$. Or it can also be defined as

$$\ln:\Bbb C\setminus\Bbb R_{\ge 0}\to \Bbb R+i(-\pi,\pi),\quad z\mapsto \ln|z|+\arg(z)\tag{2}$$

where $\arg(z)\in(-\pi,\pi)$. These definitions can also vary depending of the codomain chosen.

So if we choose $(2)$ (or some codomain-variation of it) as the definition of the complex logarithm (as @Noah did) then $\ln(-1)$ is not defined but $\ln$ is holomorphic. If we choose $(1)$ (or some codomain-variation of it) then $\ln(-1)=i\pi$ but $\ln$ is no longer holomorphic.

---

Regardless the definition we use we can see that for some $z\in\Bbb C\setminus\Bbb R_{\ge 0}$ if we fix $|z|$ then

$$\lim_{\arg(z)\to -\pi^+}\ln z=\ln|z|-i\pi\neq \lim_{\arg(z)\to \pi^-}\ln z=\ln|z|+i\pi\implies \lim_{z\to-|z|}\ln z\,\text{ does not exists}$$

because $-|z|=|z|e^{-i\pi}=|z|e^{i\pi}$ (the notation of $-\pi^+$ and $\pi^-$ is redundant with the definition of the principal argument of $z$ but I think it make clear the limits).

Hence (the principal value of) the complex logarithm cannot be continuous when is defined in $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$, so it cannot be holomorphic in this domain, neither in $\Gamma$ because $-1\in\Gamma$.